# Unbale to generate changes in JS file after saving TypeScript file

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, typescript, web-essentials

I am using Visual Studio 2012 along with TypeScript 0.9.5 and Web Essential 3.5. After I make changes in TypeScript file and save it. The changes are not saved in JavaScript file. I navigated through Tools > Options > Web Essentials > TypeScript in VS 2012 but found the options have changed. Earlier I was using TS 0.8.1 and WebEssentials 2.8 and everything was working.

Please provide your suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a link through to Tim LaBonne's blog where he outlines the changes needed to the project file to support Compile on Save.

http://www.timlabonne.com/2013/07/getting-compile-on-save-to-work-for-typescript-in-vs2012/

You should also update to the latest Web Essentials ( version 3.6.5 as at time of question posted ).