# Typescript compiler not found issue

Tags: typescript

I upgraded to TypeScript 0.9.5 and lost compile-on-save feature in visual studio.

Someone asked same question here.  It could be WebEssentials issue only but I would like to know if there is any solution.

[The TypeScript compiler couldn't be found](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21984156/2805403)

There is also a path length issue in tsc compiler. It sometimes fails saying "Cannot resolve reference" or "file not found".  This issue was supposed to be resolved with Typescript 0.9.5.

Please let me know if other people are facing the same issues.

Comment: related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21989661/unbale-to-generate-changes-in-js-file-after-saving-typescript-file

Comment: Upgraded from which version of typescript.  Ensure you have the latest WebEssentials - currently 3.6.5.  Look at this [Tim LaBonne](http://www.timlabonne.com/2013/07/getting-compile-on-save-to-work-for-typescript-in-vs2012/) blog post for updates to your project file you might need to apply.